# Consent Popup not triggering on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a popup to appear when the ID is click on. In the popup there would be two buttons: one to accept, which places a true value in local storage. So the user will not see popup again, if they accepted. The other button is decline, which simply closes the the popup, places nothing in local storage, and will popup again if ID is clicked on again.

Everything in the code is working as I would like, except I would like it to activate on an ID click event. I have tried replacing:

```
window.onload = () => {

with

$( "#gtranslate_popup" ).click(function() {
```

HTML

```
<div id="gtranslate_popup">
Click Here
</div>
<div id="consent_popup" class="hidden">
    <div id="consent_popup_content">
        <h3>Language Selection</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan. Pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur. Praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae. Enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit. Eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
        <div id="consent-btns"><a id="gt_accept" class="btn btn-default" href="#">Accept</a> <a id="gt_decline" class="btn btn-red" href="#">Decline</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#consent_popup {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;

    &.hidden {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

#consent_popup_content {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddddd5;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: auto;
    left: 15%;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 1%;
    width: 70%;
}

#consent_popup_content h3 {
    color: #4e4646;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#consent-popup-content h3:after {
    background-color: #4e4646;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0.3em auto;
    width: 10%;
}

#consent_popup_content p {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

#consent-btns .btn {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.25em 0.75em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#consent-btns .btn-red {
    background-color: #d34727;
}
```

Script

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //Language Module Consent Popup
    const storageType = localStorage;
    const consentPropertyName = 'lang_consent';
    const shouldShowPopup = () => !storageType.getItem(consentPropertyName);
    const saveToStorage = () => storageType.setItem(consentPropertyName, true);

    window.onload = () => {

        const acceptFn = event => {
        saveToStorage(storageType);
           consentPopup.classList.add('hidden');
        }
    
        const declineFn = event => {
            consentPopup.classList.add('hidden');
        }
    
        const consentPopup = document.getElementById('consent_popup');
        const acceptBtn = document.getElementById('gt_accept');
        const declineBtn = document.getElementById('gt_decline');
    
        acceptBtn.addEventListener('click', acceptFn);
        declineBtn.addEventListener('click', declineFn);

        if (shouldShowPopup(storageType)) {
            consentPopup.classList.remove('hidden');
        }
    };
    //End of Language Module Consent Popup
});
    // End of the making the menu navigate with keyboard

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Your popup has opacity 0 but is still in the DOM and covers the ID. You need to add `pointer-events: none;` to your .hidden CSS rule. (Also note that everything your store in localStorage is force-converted to a string)

Comment: I tried your suggestion of pointer-events. There was no change. The issue is that I need to change the event from on load of page to click on ID. Which doesn't seem to work.

The local storage is only a binary of true, which is working.

Comment: You also have window.onload inside $(document).ready(), which I'm not sure will work but is not necessary anyway. Here's fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/wochj7u6/

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you, that works great. Also now I understand why you were referring to the pointer-events. :)

Answer (score 0):

The most browser disable popups by default.

Comment: It's not a popup window, just a <div>.